# Openquery convert yyyymmdd to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: oracle, ssms, openquery

I have tried

```
FROM OPENQUERY(TESTsvr, 
Select to_date(CREATE_DT, "MM/DD/YYYY") as Testing
From Test.ViewTest
```

and

```
FROM OPENQUERY(TESTsvr, 
to_char(CREATE_DT, "mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss") as Testing
From Test.ViewTest
```

but when I execute it says invalid identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with quotes:
If you are casting date into char:

```
  FROM OPENQUERY(TESTsvr, 
'select to_char(CREATE_DT, ''mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'') as Testing From Test.ViewTest')
```

If you are casting char into date:

```
  FROM OPENQUERY(TESTsvr, 
'select to_date(CREATE_DT, ''mm/dd/yyyy'') as Testing From Test.ViewTest')
```

If you are casting NUMBER(8) into date (as yyyymmdd):

```
  FROM OPENQUERY(TESTsvr, 
'select to_date(CREATE_DT, ''yyyymmdd'') as Testing From Test.ViewTest')
```

Comment: @jrussin what datatype is Test.ViewTest.CREATE_DT?

Comment: @jrussin ok it's a number but it's storing a date? What format?

Comment: It is storing as YYYYMMDD

Comment: Boom! you are the best! Idk why I made this so difficult haha.